# ionic + angular 12 dynamic meta tags not visible on page source, but sometimes it does appear in page source

Tags: angular, meta-tags, ionic5, angular12

I've this websites build with ionic 5 + Angular 12. Am trying to add meta tags which are fetched from API. So it's dynamic. It was all good until now. It was appear in page source without any issues. But now I realized some of my websites meta tags not visible in page source. But it does appear in inspect elements. This is the same code.

this is how i set meta tags:

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private metaService: Meta){
   // Set meta tags from backend data
   this.metaService.addTag({ name: 'description', content: this.appService.meta_description });
   this.metaService.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: this.appService.meta_keywords });
}
```

With this code. Sometimes it does appear in the page source, sometimes not. What can be the issue.

as below it appear in this site in pagesource
[image]

**Does it matter if these meta tags are not visible in the page source but in inspect elements?**